# accept certificate for XMLHTTP60

Tags: vba, ms-access, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send api request by VBA - MS Access 2016, in order to receive json file, when I implemented this I received the error message below

[image]

I am using Microsoft XML, V6 as reference

my code as below

```
Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

'Create a new Request Object
Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    'API code
    api_url = Me.UPC
    
    'Open a new request using our URL
    xml_obj.Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrURL:=api_url
                    
    'Send the request
    xml_obj.send
```

Comment: Can you access the URL from e.g. your browser?

Comment: I can access it with a browser warning, I should accept risks before proceed

Comment: Then you should make it so that you don't have a warning anymore in the browser. After that, XMLHTTP requests will start to work, too. That means: Open the certificate in the browser, after accepting the warning. Look at the certificate chain. If the certificate is self-signed, you need to import itself into the "Trusted Root" certificate store. If it is signed by a different, untrusted certificate, you must import *that* into the "Trusted Root" store on your machine. This can be done with certmgr.msc.